# Eventual Consistency and messaging

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, distributed, messaging, consistency

I came across this problem, and so far it seems that the only solution is stronger consistency model. The service is Amazon S3, which provides eventual consistency. We use it as blob storage backend.

The problem is, we introduced messaging pattern to our application, and we love it. There's no doubt about it's benefits. However, it seems that it demands stronger consistency. Scenario:

1. subsystem acquires data from user
2. data is saved to S3
3. message is sent
4. message is received by another subsystem
5. data is read from S3
6. ...crickets. Is this the old data? Sometimes it is.

So. We tried to the obvious, send the data in the message to avoid inconsistent reading from S3. But that's pretty nasty thing to do, the message get unnecessarily big, and when the receiver is too busy or goes down, and receives the message late while there's already new data available, it fails.

Is there a solution to this or do we really need to dump S3 for some more consistent backend like RDBMS or MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

If your scenario allows for your data to always be written on S3 under a new key (by always creating new objects) then you can rely on Amazon's read-after-write consistency.

Here is Amazon's description that describes this consistency model:

> Amazon S3 buckets in the US West (Northern California), EU (Ireland),
>   Asia Pacific (Singapore), and Asia Pacific (Tokyo) Regions provide
>   read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects and eventual
>   consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES. Amazon S3 buckets in the
>   US Standard Region provide eventual consistency.

Comment: We decided to switch the blob store to MongoDB, it provides strong consistency.